# Why adding a simply star icon to my form disables the SSL?

Tags: ssl

For an unknown reason, the active SSL on my website gets unactive on 1 specify page whenever I add Internal CSS there to add star icons to the 'Review form'. When I remove that styling part, the SSL is back up again.
I really have no clue how adding a simple star icon to my form disables the SSL? Anybody has any clues, or tricks?

See visual examples, and the script of my websites review form below:

[Visual example of the form, with and without stars / active SSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl57G.png)

```
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <form action="process-review" method="post">
                                    Overall score:
                                    <br><span class="starRating1">
                                      <input id="rating5A" type="radio" name="rating1" value="5" required>
                                      <label for="rating5A">5</label>
                                      <input id="rating4A" type="radio" name="rating1" value="4">
                                      <label for="rating4A">4</label>
                                      <input id="rating3A" type="radio" name="rating1" value="3">
                                      <label for="rating3A">3</label>
                                      <input id="rating2A" type="radio" name="rating1" value="2">
                                      <label for="rating2A">2</label>
                                      <input id="rating1A" type="radio" name="rating1" value="1">
                                      <label for="rating1A">1</label>
                                    </span>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea style="background-color: #3382F8; color: white; font-size: 17px; border: 2px solid #000B68;" name="comment1" rows="5" cols="48" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
                                    <br>
                                    <br> Graphics:
                                    <br><span class="starRating2">
                                      <input id="rating5B" type="radio" name="rating2" value="5" required>
                                      <label for="rating5B">5</label>
                                      <input id="rating4B" type="radio" name="rating2" value="4">
                                      <label for="rating4B">4</label>
                                      <input id="rating3B" type="radio" name="rating2" value="3">
                                      <label for="rating3B">3</label>
                                      <input id="rating2B" type="radio" name="rating2" value="2">
                                      <label for="rating2B">2</label>
                                      <input id="rating1B" type="radio" name="rating2" value="1">
                                      <label for="rating1B">1</label>
                                    </span>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea style="background-color: #3382F8; color: white; font-size: 17px; border: 2px solid #000B68;" name="comment2" rows="2" cols="48" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
                                    <br>
                                    <br> Sound:
                                    <br><span class="starRating3">
                                      <input id="rating5C" type="radio" name="rating3" value="5" required>
                                      <label for="rating5C">5</label>
                                      <input id="rating4C" type="radio" name="rating3" value="4">
                                      <label for="rating4C">4</label>
                                      <input id="rating3C" type="radio" name="rating3" value="3">
                                      <label for="rating3C">3</label>
                                      <input id="rating2C" type="radio" name="rating3" value="2">
                                      <label for="rating2C">2</label>
                                      <input id="rating1C" type="radio" name="rating3" value="1">
                                      <label for="rating1C">1</label>
                                    </span>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea style="background-color: #3382F8; color: white; font-size: 17px; border: 2px solid #000B68;" name="comment3" rows="2" cols="48" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
                                    <br>
                                    <br> Gameplay:
                                    <br><span class="starRating4">
                                      <input id="rating5D" type="radio" name="rating4" value="5" required>
                                      <label for="rating5D">5</label>
                                      <input id="rating4D" type="radio" name="rating4" value="4">
                                      <label for="rating4D">4</label>
                                      <input id="rating3D" type="radio" name="rating4" value="3">
                                      <label for="rating3D">3</label>
                                      <input id="rating2D" type="radio" name="rating4" value="2">
                                      <label for="rating2D">2</label>
                                      <input id="rating1D" type="radio" name="rating4" value="1">
                                      <label for="rating1D">1</label>
                                    </span>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea style="background-color: #3382F8; color: white; font-size: 17px; border: 2px solid #000B68;" name="comment4" rows="2" cols="48" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
                                    <br>
                                    <br> Story:
                                    <br><span class="starRating5">
                                      <input id="rating5E" type="radio" name="rating5" value="5" required>
                                      <label for="rating5E">5</label>
                                      <input id="rating4E" type="radio" name="rating5" value="4">
                                      <label for="rating4E">4</label>
                                      <input id="rating3E" type="radio" name="rating5" value="3">
                                      <label for="rating3E">3</label>
                                      <input id="rating2E" type="radio" name="rating5" value="2">
                                      <label for="rating2E">2</label>
                                      <input id="rating1E" type="radio" name="rating5" value="1">
                                      <label for="rating1E">1</label>
                                    </span>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea style="background-color: #3382F8; color: white; font-size: 17px; border: 2px solid #000B68;" name="comment5" rows="2" cols="48" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
                                    <br>
                                    <br> User Interface:
                                    <br><span class="starRating6">
                                      <input id="rating5F" type="radio" name="rating6" value="5" required>
                                      <label for="rating5F">5</label>
                                      <input id="rating4F" type="radio" name="rating6" value="4">
                                      <label for="rating4F">4</label>
                                      <input id="rating3F" type="radio" name="rating6" value="3">
                                      <label for="rating3F">3</label>
                                      <input id="rating2F" type="radio" name="rating6" value="2">
                                      <label for="rating2F">2</label>
                                      <input id="rating1F" type="radio" name="rating6" value="1">
                                      <label for="rating1F">1</label>
                                    </span>
                                    <br>
                                    <textarea style="background-color: #3382F8; color: white; font-size: 17px; border: 2px solid #000B68;" name="comment6" rows="2" cols="48" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    <br> Name* (will be published with your review):
                                    <br>
                                    <input style="background-color: #3382F8; color: white; font-size: 17px; border: 2px solid #000B68;" type="text" name="name1" size="50" maxlength="50" required/>
                                    <br>
                                    <br> E-mail (hidden with your review):
                                    <br>
                                    <input style="background-color: #3382F8; color: white; font-size: 17px; border: 2px solid #000B68;" type="text" name="email1" size="50" maxlength="50" />
                                    <br>
                                    <br> Anti-bot verification*:
                                    <div class="check">
                                    <label>4 x 3 =</label>
                                    <input min="0" max="999999" style="background-color: #3382F8; color: white; font-size: 17px; border: 2px solid #000B68;" type="number" name="not_robot1" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <br>
                                    <input style="background-color: #3382F8; color: white; font-size: 17px; border: 2px solid #000B68;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

```
<head>
    <style>
        .starRating1:not(old) {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 7.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                }

                .starRating1:not(old) > input {
                    margin-right: -100%;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                .starRating1:not(old) > label {
                    display: block;
                    float: right;
                    position: relative;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-off.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                }

                .starRating1:not(old) > label:before {
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    width: 1.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-on.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
                }

                .starRating1:not(old) > label:hover:before,
                .starRating1:not(old) > label:hover ~ label:before,
                .starRating1:not(:hover) >:checked ~ label:before {
                    opacity: 1;
                }

                .starRating2:not(old) {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 7.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                }

                .starRating2:not(old) > input {
                    margin-right: -100%;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                .starRating2:not(old) > label {
                    display: block;
                    float: right;
                    position: relative;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-off.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                }

                .starRating2:not(old) > label:before {
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    width: 1.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-on.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
                }

                .starRating2:not(old) > label:hover:before,
                .starRating2:not(old) > label:hover ~ label:before,
                .starRating2:not(:hover) >:checked ~ label:before {
                    opacity: 1;
                }

                .starRating3:not(old) {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 7.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                }

                .starRating3:not(old) > input {
                    margin-right: -100%;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                .starRating3:not(old) > label {
                    display: block;
                    float: right;
                    position: relative;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-off.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                }

                .starRating3:not(old) > label:before {
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    width: 1.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-on.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
                }

                .starRating3:not(old) > label:hover:before,
                .starRating3:not(old) > label:hover ~ label:before,
                .starRating3:not(:hover) >:checked ~ label:before {
                    opacity: 1;
                }

                .starRating4:not(old) {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 7.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                }

                .starRating4:not(old) > input {
                    margin-right: -100%;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                .starRating4:not(old) > label {
                    display: block;
                    float: right;
                    position: relative;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-off.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                }

                .starRating4:not(old) > label:before {
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    width: 1.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-on.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
                }

                .starRating4:not(old) > label:hover:before,
                .starRating4:not(old) > label:hover ~ label:before,
                .starRating4:not(:hover) >:checked ~ label:before {
                    opacity: 1;
                }

                .starRating5:not(old) {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 7.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                }

                .starRating5:not(old) > input {
                    margin-right: -100%;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                .starRating5:not(old) > label {
                    display: block;
                    float: right;
                    position: relative;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-off.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                }

                .starRating5:not(old) > label:before {
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    width: 1.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-on.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
                }

                .starRating5:not(old) > label:hover:before,
                .starRating5:not(old) > label:hover ~ label:before,
                .starRating5:not(:hover) >:checked ~ label:before {
                    opacity: 1;
                }

                .starRating6:not(old) {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 7.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                }

                .starRating6:not(old) > input {
                    margin-right: -100%;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                .starRating6:not(old) > label {
                    display: block;
                    float: right;
                    position: relative;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-off.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                }

                .starRating6:not(old) > label:before {
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    width: 1.5em;
                    height: 1.5em;
                    background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-on.png');
                    background-size: contain;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
                }

                .starRating6:not(old) > label:hover:before,
                .starRating6:not(old) > label:hover ~ label:before,
                .starRating6:not(:hover) >:checked ~ label:before {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Is your star an image? Then it is possible that it is labeled as unsafe.https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87987/https-connection-is-not-safe-due-to-images/87988

Comment: Yes the star is an image. And due to your post and what I read on that link, I already solved the problem instantly! It seems that I had to use 'https' insead of 'http' when I link to star images in my form. Thanks alot for your help, I never expected this problem to be solved so quick!

Comment: No problem, when you are around long enough your problem solving will improve drastically ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
background: url('http://empireofthewicked.com/images/star-off.png');
```

'http' part should be 'https' for a safe connection. Every image served must come from an 'https' connection. So if you load it externally from 'http' it will be labeled as unsafe. You can solve it by loading it from your own server or use the 'https' version if available.